# How to execute some initial startup code on a IIS hosted WCF app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I'm trying to find a hook / way to run some initial code to wire up a bunch of things before a service is called.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a simple way would be a static constructor on your service class? Presumably global.asax works too. Yet another route would be to write and register an http-module that listens to startup.

Comment: global.asax works nicely, was weird, was having problems with it initially.

overall, its a painful learning experience this WCF :)  Not to mention the hassles of doing username / password validation!   On the plus side, everything's trivial once you know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could to implement an `IServiceBehavior`.

Comment: hmmm, looks potentially promising!